# How teracopy replace default windows copy

Tags: windows, file-io

I asked this question [windows file copy internals (on the fly encryption)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220382/windows-file-copy-internals-on-the-fly-encryption) to know how windows file copy system works because i want to encrypt all copied files but i don't give my answer (Competently) so i decide to replace default windows copy by my encryption program. And now my question is :How teracopy replace default windows copy?

Comment: Probably one or more shell hooks.  But that won't cover all file copies, only those started from Explorer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks, I wrote a shell hook using [ICopyHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776049(v=vs.85).aspx) but it's only work for folders ! and not for files :( How can i write a shell hook for files ??? What i should to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can change between TeraCopy and the default Windows copy function by launching TeraCopy, rightclicking on its interface, hitting Preferences, and toggling "Use TeraCopy as default copy handler".